# Django don't accept saas files but accept css files

Tags: html, css, django, saas

Please Help me.

When I running my app in cmd My website dont work css (which have saas and css)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Settinngs.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Head.html

```
   {% load static %}

 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/aos.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/ionicons.min.css' %}">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/flaticon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/icomoon.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
  </head>
```

script.html

```
{% load static %}

 <script src="j{% static 's/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/aos.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/scrollax.min.js' %}"></script>  
  <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
```

But when I us only css files which dont have saas then working normal.
What is problem help me?

Answer (score 1):

Well SCSS/LESS are just fancy and easier way to write CSS. Browser can't read them unless they are compiled to CSS files.

That is why you need to compile them to CSS and then include CSS file in project. Not SCSS/LESS directly